# Не рендериться часть объекта в юнити при повороте камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, render

Создаю игру, делаю POV персонажа(моделька, анимации и тд), все работает отлично но когда я направляю камеру вниз и начинаю ходить, то когда воспроизводиться анимация не рендериться
половина объекта ноги (почему то именно левой).Проблема не в модели и анимациях.Пробувал менять несколько раз ничего не помогло.Я использую плагин cinemachine, менял FOW помогло наполовину, но если опустите камеру чуть ниже центра то опять появляется эта проблема.Я не знаю с чем это связано так как это уже не первый мой опыт создания такой игры, и этот баг вижу впервые